# iOS device attitude for augmented reality

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, three.js, augmented-reality

I want to track the device motion of my iPhone using swift and then hand it over to a WebView to rotate a THREE.js accordingly. 
(The reason for using THREE.js instead doing the rendering in OpenGL is for compatibility reasons to our website.)

Tracking of the device motion is currently done in swift using

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1
motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/60
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true;

motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!) {
    (motionData: CMDeviceMotion?, NSError) -> Void in
    self.outputData(motionData!.attitude.quaternion.x, motionData!.attitude.quaternion.y, motionData!.attitude.quaternion.z, motionData!.attitude.quaternion.w)

    if(NSError != nil) {
        print("\(NSError)")
    }
}
```

The outputData function just hands over the four parameter to THREE.js where the following code is exectuted:

```
camera.quaternion.set(x, y, z, w);
```

Unfortunately, it is not working at all.

I know, that there is a rotation by 90° missing as the attitude is aligned for the phone lying on the table instead of held in front of the user, but this would be the next step.

For simplicity the app is currently locked to portrait mode only.

Any idea how to transform the data from iOS attitude.quaternion to a way THREE.js (or any other webGL/OpenGL based engine) could work with?

Comment: Perhaps the source code in [DeviceOrientationControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js) will be helpful.

Comment: I already took a look into it and had it working before using this class, but I need to have the attitude working through native iOS and it seems, that the values received through window.addEventListener( 'deviceorientation') differs from those from motionData.attitude .